# R: Creating a column by adding values of two previous columns

Tags: r

I am working in R. I have typed in the command :

```
table(shoppingdata$Identifier, shoppingdata$Coupon)
```

I have the following data:

```
           FALSE TRUE
  197386     0    5

  197388     0    2

  197390     2    0

  197392     0    3

  197394     1    0

  197397     0    1

  197398     1    1

  197400     0    4

  197402     1    5

  197406     0    5
```

1. First of all, I cannot name the vectors FALSE and TRUE by something else, e.g couponused.
2. Most importantly, I want to create a third column which is the sum of FALSE+TRUE( Coupon used+coupon not used= number of visits). The actual columns contain hundreds of entries.

The solution is not obvious at all.

Comment: this is the most basic R thing, do you have a dataframe , do you know `x+y`

Comment: [data frames](http://www.statmethods.net/input/datatypes.html) in R

Comment: You definitely SHOULD rename your columns. Unless you want to be back-ticking all over the place

Answer (score 2):

You have stumbled into the abyss of R data types, through no fault of your own.

Assuming that `shoppingdata` is a data frame,

```
table(shoppingdata$Identifier, shoppingdata$Coupon)
```

creates an object of type "table". One would think that using, e.g.

```
as.data.frame(table(shoppingdata$Identifier, shoppingdata$Coupon))
```

would turn this into a data frame with the same format as in the printout, but, as the example below shows, it does not!

```
# example
data <- data.frame(ID=rep(1:5,each=10),coupon=(sample(c(T,F),50,replace=T)))
# creates "contingency table", not a data frame.
t <- table(data)
t
#    coupon
# ID  FALSE TRUE
#   1     5    5
#   2     3    7
#   3     4    6
#   4     6    4
#   5     3    7

as.data.frame(t)  # not useful!!
#    ID coupon Freq
# 1   1  FALSE    5
# 2   2  FALSE    3
# 3   3  FALSE    4
# 4   4  FALSE    6
# 5   5  FALSE    3
# 6   1   TRUE    5
# 7   2   TRUE    7
# 8   3   TRUE    6
# 9   4   TRUE    4
# 10  5   TRUE    7

# this works...
coupons  <- data.frame(ID=rownames(t),not.used=t[,1],used=t[,2])
# add two columns to make a third
coupons$total <- coupons$used + coupons$not.used
# or, less typing
coupons$ total <- with(coupons,not.used+used)
```

FWIW, I think yours is a perfectly reasonable question. The reason more people don't use R is that it has an extremely steep learning curve, and the documentation is not very good. On the other hand, once you've climbed that learning curve, R is astonishingly powerful.

Comment: Or you can use `as.data.frame.matrix` to get your "coupons" `data.frame`: `setNames(as.data.frame.matrix(Tab), c("not.used", "used"))`

Comment: Or, all in one shot: `cbind(ID = rownames(Tab), 
      setNames(as.data.frame.matrix(Tab), 
               c("not.used", "used")),
      Total = rowSums(Tab))` :-)