# Unlist a dataframe variable in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, coerce

I have a dataframe bask.df as below.

```
     basko1 basko2 
1st       6      1 
2nd      12      1 
3rd       8      8 
4th       4      5 
5th       1      2 
6th       8      9 
7th       1      2 
8th       8      9 
9th      12     14 
10th     15     10 
11th      3      6 
12th      5      2 
13th      4      6 
14th      3      1 
15th      4      6 
16th      3      1
```

I want to add a third column named total, which is the sum of the integers in basko1 and basko2 columns.

When I try in R as :

```
bask.df['total'] <- as.numeric(bask.df['basko1']) + as.numeric(bask.df['basko2']) ,
```

it gives me the error as

`Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Is bask.df[basko1] and bask.df[basko2], which are seemingly vectors, actually present as lists here ? Or I am doing anything else wrong ?

Comment: Try `bask.df$basko1 + bask.df$basko2`.

Comment: You just need `rowSums(bask.df)`

Comment: Yes, it works but I want to understand he concept of whether the variables of dataframe are present as lists ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: Creating a column by adding values of two previous columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685727/r-creating-a-column-by-adding-values-of-two-previous-columns)

Comment: This is in no way a duplicate.

Comment: `is.list(data.frame(x = 1:10))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the OP's code is because of applying `as.numeric` to a `data.frame` i.e. `bask.df['basko1']` us still a `data.frame` with a single column.  The `as.numeric` can be applied to `vector` or `matrix`

```
bask.df['total'] <- as.numeric(bask.df[,'basko1']) + as.numeric(bask.df[,'basko2'])
```

In the above code, we added `,` to make it `vector` or it can be done with `[[` i.e. `bask.df[['bask01']]`

A compact approach would be

```
bask.df['total'] <- with(bask.df, bask.o1 + basko2)
```

Comment: I would use `[[` or `$` instead of relying on `[` to drop single-column dfs to vectors. This "feature" has tripped me up countless times when I wasn't expecting it.

Comment: Plus, `[[` and `$` mean it'll also work with those tybbly-thingies.